# Retrieve the text node that is not part of <a> with XPATH, python selenium?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

On the following linke: https://classicdb.ch/?quest=788

here at `//*[@id="main-contents"]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td`
it contains a text

> Mottled Boar slain (10)

```
//*[@id="main-contents"]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a
```

contains only:

> Mottled Boar

And I only need the second part that contains:

> slain (10)

In python with selenium i tried accessing the node directly with:

```
//*[@id="main-contents"]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/text()
```

However the webdriver can contain only webelements and not text nodes.

> The result of the xpa th expression
>   "//*[@id="main-contents"]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a/following-sibling::text()"
>   is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

I also tried:

```
//*[@id="main-contents"]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a/following-sibling::text()
```

But does returns the same error that it should be an element not an object text.

I have found a workaround by first selecting the  text only, then subtracting that from the whole text - but that's ugly.
How do achieve this properly?

Thank you!

EDIT: I must not use specific variables in the code like 'slain' or 'Mottled Boar', because these variables can change in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath.

```
//table[@class='iconlist']//tr//td[contains(.,'slain')]//a[contains(.,'Mottled Boar')]
```

**Edit**

```
//table[@class='iconlist']//tr//td//a
```

Use **javaScript** executor. where `firstChild` will return the `Mottled Boar` and 
`lastChild` will return `slain (10)`

```
driver.get("https://classicdb.ch/?quest=788")
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='iconlist']//tr//td[1]")))
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='iconlist']//tr//td[1]")))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I must not use specific variables in the code like 'slain' or 'Mottled Boar'
edit: because these variables can change.

edit2: i will add this condition in my question

Comment: This gets only the first part Mottled Boar - I need the other part where it says 'slain (10)'

Comment: @masky007 : to get the `slain (10)` you need to use javascript executor to return last node value.

Comment: @masky007 : last child will return `slain (10)` and first child  will retrun `Mottled Boar` let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah that does it, thanks! - You can only leave the last part in your answer as that answers the question
Where can I learn more about this - I have never worked with Java before though.

Answer (score 0):

You xpath is correct. you can try this approach to get the text directly from that node. you will need lxml import.

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
myText = tree.xpath("//*[@id='main-contents']/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a/following-sibling::text()")

print(str(myText).replace('\\t', ''))
```